# 2 events in 1 onPress via React Native

Tags: react-native

**How Can I Mix This 2 Events in 1 onPress?**

```
<TouchableHighlight
onPress={() => { this.setModalVisible(true, img) }}    
onPress={() => this.setState({ paused: !this.state.paused })}
>
```

They work alone, but I want to work both by pressing `TouchableHighlight`

Comment: Have you tried like this? `<TouchableHighlight
onPress={() => { this.setModalVisible(true, img); this.setState({ paused: !this.state.paused }) }}` Hope it helps

Comment: Solved, Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved By soutot.

```
 <TouchableHighlight 
    onPress={() => { this.setModalVisible(true, img); this.setState({ paused: !this.state.paused }) }}
    >
```